# How to hide the ID column in the data grid but still being able to get it if the user clicks or sorts the record

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid

I have written the following code to display the fields of my choice in DataGrid. What I want to do is to hide the ID column of COUNTRY table in the DataGrid. So it should not appear to the user. But I also want to still get the ID of COUNTRY table record if the user click on any column or sorts the DataGrid. 
Kindly help me. What should I do? What is missing in this code?

```
OleDbDataAdapter da;
    DataSet ds;

    public void showGrid()
    {
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(ConnString);
        string sql = @"Select id, country_code, country_name , from country";
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql,conn);
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds, "Cat");
            // Turn this off so column names do not come from data source
            dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
            dataGridView1.DataMember = "Cat";
            dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Code";
            dataGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Name";

            dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "country_code";
            dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "country_name";

            dataGridView1.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "country_code" ;    
            dataGridView1.Columns[1].DataPropertyName = "country_name"; 
            conn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            conn.Close();
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just hide it - add id column with width = 0.

Answer (score 4):

Add this line in Form1_Load method

```
dataGridView1.Columns[0].Visible = false;
```

Please Mark as Answer, if this solves your problem

[image: Click on Tick sign next to the answer, in case you don't know :P]

Comment: ha ha ha... that was good one...i wish i could give +1 for that as well